# Help expressing the second derivatives in terms of a change of variable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am trying to express the second derivatives of a function $U(x,y)$ in terms of a change of variable $\alpha (x,y)$ and $\beta(x,y)$ using the chain rule and that:
$$U_x=\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}U_{ \alpha}+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}U_{ \beta} \quad \quad U_y=\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y}U_{ \alpha}+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial y}U_{ \beta},  $$
Notice that:
$$U_{xx}=\frac{\partial^2\alpha}{\partial x^2}U_{ \alpha}+\frac{\partial U_\alpha}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}+      \frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial x^2}U_{ \beta}+\frac{\partial U_\beta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}, $$
and
$$ \frac{\partial U_\alpha}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha}
 \right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}
 \right)$$

And there I am not sure how to continue, please some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, you're trying to get $\partial U_\alpha /\partial x$ in terms of $\alpha$- and $\beta$-derivatives. What you're looking for is
$$
\frac{\partial U_\alpha}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}U_{\alpha\alpha} + \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} U_{\alpha\beta}
$$
so that
$$U_{xx}=\frac{\partial^2\alpha}{\partial x^2}U_{ \alpha}+\left(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}U_{\alpha\alpha} + \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} U_{\alpha\beta}\right) \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}+      \frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial x^2}U_{ \beta}+\left( \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}U_{\alpha\beta} + \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} U_{\beta\beta}\right)\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}
\\ =  \frac{\partial^2\alpha}{\partial x^2}U_{ \alpha}+  \frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial x^2}U_{ \beta} +\left(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}\right)^2U_{\alpha\alpha} + 2\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} U_{\alpha\beta}+ \left(\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}\right)^2 U_{\beta\beta}$$